# ACME challenge DNS data is not accessible within route53 module

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to generate ssl certicates through ansible. acme_certificate module populates acme_data with challenge data. I suppose to update those challenge DNS records in my DNS provider which is Route53.

I use Route53 module to update the challenge data received above. acme_data.challenge_data is an array and I can verify it through debug. For some reason, route53 is unable to interpret that record as array and fail with undefined variable item.

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/SenG/Code/Yii2-Starter-Kit-Nginx-Aws-Setup/aws/tasks/ssl-cert.yml': line 80, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Publish the challenge to DNS\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

```yaml
- name: Create certificate storage directory
  delegate_to: "{{remote_host}}"
  become: true
  become_user: SenG
  file:
    dest: "{{item.path}}"
    mode: 0750
    state: directory
  with_items:
  - path: ~/letsencrypt
  - path: ~/letsencrypt

- name: create temporary directory
  tempfile:
    state: directory
  register: tempdir

# - name: Pull keys/files
#   command: |
#     /usr/bin/rsync --recursive "{{remote_host}}:~/letsencrypt" "{{tempdir.path}}"

- name: Create RSA key to be used for ansible account
  openssl_privatekey:
    path: "{{tempdir.path}}/letsencrypt_account.pem"
    size: 4096
    type: RSA

- name: Create RSA key to be used for certificate
  openssl_privatekey:
    path: "{{tempdir.path}}/{{cert_name}}.key"
    size: 4096
    type: RSA

- name: report cert value
  debug:
    var: cert
    verbosity: 1

- name: Create CSR for certificate
  openssl_csr:
    path: "{{tempdir.path}}/{{cert_name}}.csr"
    privatekey_path: "{{tempdir.path}}/{{cert_name}}.key"
    country_name: IN
    state_or_province_name: TN
    organization_name: "{{cert.organization_name}}"
    email_address: "{{cert.email_address}}"
    common_name: "{{cert.common_name}}"
    subject_alt_name: "{{cert.subject_alt_name}}"

- name: Get ACME challenge
  acme_certificate:
    account_email: "{{cert.email_address}}"
    account_key: "{{tempdir.path}}/letsencrypt_account.pem"
    acme_directory: "{{acme_directory}}"
    acme_version: 2
    challenge: dns-01
    chain_dest:  "{{tempdir.path}}/intermediate.pem"
    csr: "{{tempdir.path}}/{{cert_name}}.csr"
    dest: "{{tempdir.path}}/{{cert_name}}.cert"
    terms_agreed: yes
    remaining_days: "{{remaining_days}}"
  register: acme_data

- debug:
    var: acme_data

- name: Publish the challenge to DNS
  route53:
    zone: "{{ app_domain}}"
    record: "{{ item.key }}"
    type: TXT
    ttl: 60
    # Note: item.value is a list of TXT entries, and route53
    # requires every entry to be enclosed in quotes
    value: "{{ item.value | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\"\\1\"' ) | list }}"
    access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
    secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
    with_dict: "{{acme_data.challenge_data_dns}}"
    when: acme_data is changed

- name: Wait a bit so that DNS replication happens
  pause:
    seconds: 60
  when: acme_data is changed

- name: Get certificate
  acme_certificate:
    account_email: "{{cert.email_address}}"
    account_key: "{{tempdir.path}}/letsencrypt_account.pem"
    acme_directory: "{{acme_directory}}"
    acme_version: 2
    challenge: dns-01
    chain_dest:  "{{tempdir.path}}/intermediate.pem"
    csr: "{{tempdir.path}}/{{cert_name}}.csr"
    dest: "{{tempdir.path}}/{{cert_name}}.cert"
    terms_agreed: yes
    remaining_days: "{{remaining_days}}"
    data: "{{acme_data}}"
  when: acme_data is changed
```

Debug data

```yaml
        "challenge_data_dns": {
            "_acme-challenge.practice-akash-ajay.plts.in": [
                "knXBPNL3Rm-aSNaYL23aR84f9E72GYjMBIgHPAOgwF4"
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is using `with_dict` and `when` as parameter of the module, try as below

```yaml
- name: Publish the challenge to DNS
  route53:
    zone: "{{ app_domain}}"
    record: "{{ item.key }}"
    type: TXT
    ttl: 60
    # Note: item.value is a list of TXT entries, and route53
    # requires every entry to be enclosed in quotes
    value: "{{ item.value | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\"\\1\"' ) | list }}"
    access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
    secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
  with_dict: "{{acme_data.challenge_data_dns}}"
  when: acme_data is changed
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know module param. I'm still working on other pieces, the solution will be published here once done.

https://github.com/PearlThoughts/Yii2-Starter-Kit-Nginx-Aws-Setup